# unable to get ldap server details python3

Tags: python-3.6, ldap3

I am getting none as output for below code

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM
server = Server('servername', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user="uname", password="pwd", authentication=NTLM)
print(server.info)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must bind to the server for reading info. Just use “conn.bind()” to open the connection before printing.